# Puts and times method on numbers

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
puts 1.times { puts 2.times { puts 3.times { puts 4 } } }
```

Outputs this:

```
4 4 4 3 4 4 4 3 2 1
```

I would expect Ruby to output the return value of the `times` method, but it doesn't seem to do that. It prints out the number that `times` is being called on. What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really get that output either, so let's dissect it, starting with the innermost expression:

```
puts 4
# 4           <- this should denote output
#=> nil       <- this should denote return value
```

It prints `4` and returns `nil` ([`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns `nil`).

Wrapping it in `3.times { ... }` prints `4` 3 times:

```
3.times { puts 4 }
# 4
# 4
# 4
#=> 3
```

But instead of returning `nil`, it returns `3`. This is because [`times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-times) always returns the receiver (i.e. the integer you call `times` on).

Now let's add another `puts`:

```
puts 3.times { puts 4 }
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
#=> nil
```

Same as above, but also prints the result of `3.times { ... }`, i.e. `3`.

Wrapping everything in `2.times { ... }` duplicates the above output:

```
2.times { puts 3.times { puts 4 } }
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
#=> 2
```

It also returns `2` instead of `nil` because of `2.times { ... }`.

Adding `puts` prints that `2`:

```
puts 2.times { puts 3.times { puts 4 } }
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 2
#=> nil
```

Wrapping this in `1.times { ... }` produces the same output, but changes the result from `nil` to `1`:

```
1.times { puts 2.times { puts 3.times { puts 4 } } }
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 2
#=> 1
```

Adding the last `puts` prints that `1`:

```
puts 1.times { puts 2.times { puts 3.times { puts 4 } } }
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 3
# 2
# 1
#=> nil
```

Comment: Ah gotcha. Didn't realize that the `times` method returns the receiver. Makes sense now. Thanks for the detailed breakdown!

Answer (score 7):

You've got a (quasi) loop within a loop within a loop so Ruby's doing exactly what you're asking of it. The way these loops are evaluated is, generally speaking, from the inside out.

The return value from `times` is the number given in the first place, so `3.times` returns `3`.

With all that in mind you can interpret what's happening as this:

```
4 # First iteration of 3.times { puts 4 }
4
4
3 # Return value of 3.times displayed
4 # Second iteration of 3.times { puts 4 }
4
4
3 # Return value of 3.times displayed
2 # Return value of 2.times displayed
1 # Return value of 1.times displayed
```

Now when I see code like `puts 3.times` that's usually a mistake, same goes for `puts array.each ...` where someone probably means `.map`.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess I'd expect Ruby to output the return value of the `times` method, but it doesn't seem to do that. It prints out the number that `times` is being called on.

[That *is* the return value of the `times` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times):

> ## `times {|i| block }` → `self`